# Файл отправки почтовых шаблонов в Битриксе

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в Битриксе находится файл отправки почтовых шаблонов? На сайте есть форма, которая сделана через "Сервисы" - "Веб-формы", к которой прикреплен почтовый шаблон. Боты уже совсем одолели своим спамом. Пытался сначала в шаблоне формы работать - боты всё равно отправляют форму.

В форме action указывает только на страницу, на которой находится форма (/contacts/). Если это поможет, то стоит решение Аспро (aspro_tires2).

Answer (score 0):

Почтовые шаблоны находятся по пути: `site.ru/bitrix/admin/message_admin.php?lang=ru`, далее вам надо найти нужный почтовый шаблон/шаблоны и поправить.

Сам "файл отправить почтовых шаблонов" (конечно не правильно так говорить), он не один и не стоит в этих файлах код менять. Легче тогда воспользоваться перехватом события отправки почты ([документация](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbeforeeventsend.php)) и как-то проверять, что форму заполнил не бот.

Но зачем такие муки, когда можно подключить "капчу"? Та же капча от битрикса или от гугля версии 2 или еще лучше версии 3, причем Аспро поддерживает капчу от гугля обоих версий в некоторых решений своих разработок. И капча поможет избавиться от 99% спама.

Comment: Я подключал стандартную капчу и капчу, которые Аспро сделали в своей сборке. Ни одна из них не сработала. Боты как написывали, так и продолжили это делать. Так же я ставил дополнительные плагины из маркетплейса, на версию 2 и 3, они тоже не дали никакого результата.